# My form input is returning empty in my GET request in express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I have a form that I want the user to input a name so i can search my mongodb for it but in my GET reqest the name inputted is coming up empty.

index.ejs:

```
  <form action="entry" method="GET">
    <label>Enter Name <input  type="text" name="name"></label>
    <input class="submitbtn" type="submit" value="name" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger">
    </form>

  </div>
```

entry.ejs:

```
router.get("/entry" , async(req, res) => {
 
  const allEntries = await  dailyUsage.find();

  const {name} = req.body;
  
  console.log(name)
```

console log is showing the name as empty

Comment: Have you installed body parse in your app.js?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `body-parser` before setting up the routes. you can check [body-parse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser)

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express()

// parse various different custom JSON types as JSON
app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/*+json' }))

// parse some custom thing into a Buffer
app.use(bodyParser.raw({ type: 'application/vnd.custom-type' }))

// YOUR ROUTES HERE
```

Also you can use middleware like this.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
   var data = "";
   req.on('data', function(chunk){ data += chunk})
   req.on('end', function(){
       req.rawBody = data;
       req.jsonBody = JSON.parse(data);
       next();
   })
})
```

and use `req.jsonBody` instead of `req.body` if you are going with the middleware approach.

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using body-parser

Comment: Yes, in that case, you need to use middleware. let me update my answer for that.

Comment: Hi i have tried both apporaches and im still getting undefied. Im getting the input from a index.ejs file which im handling the Post request in entry.js I never use app.js

Comment: where have you defined express()?